# How to run jQuery code when user scrolls to end of specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my sample code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            // Run code here...

    }
});
```

I use the above code to execute stuff when user scroll to bottom of page. Instead, how can I make the code executed when user scroll to bottom of specific element (e.g. #content) and not the whole document.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should probably work.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(elem).position().top + $(elem).height() /* add padding if needed. */) {

            // Run code here...

    }
});
```

Comment: Hm, maybe not `position()` but `offset()`?

Comment: I applied it but it gives weird behaviour. I think something is not right here.

Comment: @Parth Thakkar I tried both. :( none seems to run the code when I scroll to bottom of my element.

Comment: ohk!!! wait...the code will run when you reach beyond (below?) the _top_ of the element...we didn't add any height...i'll just edit

Comment: Do not know what is wrong, but it does not execute anything at all now. if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#content').position().top + $('#content').height()) {

Comment: sure? Fiddle tells just another story...check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGtwD/

Comment: Could the problem related to a setting in css for that element?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11751/discussion-between-parth-thakkar-and-ahmed-fouad)